# Why am I getting Warning NU1605, which appeared out of the clear blue

Tags: xamarin, compiler-errors

I had a working app when suddenly I got this warning:
"Warning NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 6.2.9 to 6.1.9."
In trying to figure out what is going on, I found that a new project with no added code will get this error too.
I also found that I could open the .csproj file in Notepad and change the line from 6.1.9 to 6.2.9 but wonder why I have to do this or what else I should be doing.

Answer (score 0):

> "Warning NU1605 Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 6.2.9 to 6.1.9."

From shared warnning log, you need to update Nuget Package (**Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform**) form `6.1.9` to `6.2.9`.

About updating can follow bellow steps:

Click ***Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Manange Nuget Packages for Solution...***

[image]

Then in Installed will see the nuget package there:

[image]

Select the neeed version to install:

[image]